# firebug displays count of console printed text

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, firebug, cgridview

i have a script written as following...

```
$('#sessions-grid .refreshdata').live('click', function(e) {
         console.log('came in sessions-grid .refreshdata');
      });
```

My issue in firbug is, its showing console text as below and everytime i clieck the button it doesnt appear again instead a count is there and it increases..

can any one tell me what does this means? i think because of this i am having an issue while trying to do some work in yii cgridview.

i am think weather when i press once, it goes in and keep it looping than finishing the click and stopping and when i click again print the same rather increment.

[image]

Comment: Is `'#sessions-grid .refreshdata'` selecting multiple elements in a way that a click event can bubble between them? Did you try `e.stopPropagation()`? BTW, don't know if your program's logic relies on event propagation.

Comment: @Prusse what is e.stopPropagation() used for ?

Comment: @Prusse i used e.stopImmediatePropagation(); but still its the same.

Comment: u r trying to print the ame data each time so instead of showing the same data repetedly it is showing the data and the no of times it printed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, Firebug groups the console messages if they are the same.

In version **1.12.1**, there is a new option called `console.groupLogMessages` that you can use to disable this behaviour.

Steps:

1. Enter `about:config` in the address bar
2. Search for `console.groupLogMessages`
3. Double click it to set it to `false`

For the full list of Firebug preferences and their description see the [Firebug Preferences Page](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Preferences)